# python error : 'module' object is not callable "math.ceil"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ive the following function which is do POST request to provider , I need to add new param to post request to incress the timeout ( which is by default is 5 mints i want to incress it to 1 hour , i did changes but i keep getting errors

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/lvptest/lvp_upload.py", line 226, in run
    op = uploadMedia(mediaName, "PyUploader", env)
  File "/opt/lvptest/lvp_upload.py", line 121, in uploadMedia
    expires = math.ceil(time() + 3000) ["expires"]
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is my function

```
def uploadMedia(filepath, description, env):

    global verbose
    global config

    orgId = config[env]["org_id"]
    accessKey = config[env]["access_key"]
    secret = config[env]["secret"]
    expires = math.ceil(time() + 3000) ["expires"]
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    baseUrl = "http://api.videoplatform.limelight.com/rest/organizations/%s/media" %(orgId)

    signedUrl =  lvp_auth_util.authenticate_request("POST", baseUrl, accessKey, secret, expires)
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(c.HEADER, 0)
    c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [('title', filename), ("description", description), (("media_file", (c.FORM_FILE, filepath)))])
    if verbose:
        c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)
    bodyOutput = StringIO()
    headersOutput = StringIO()
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, bodyOutput.write)
    c.setopt(c.URL, signedUrl)
    c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, headersOutput.write)
    try:
        c.perform()
        c.close()
```

Any tips if im mistaken adding param "expires" ?

here is example how is my POST request looks like

```
POST /rest/organizations/9fafklsdf/media?access_key=sfdfsdfsdfsdfsdf89234 &expires=1400406364&signature=Mc9Qsd4sdgdfg0iEOFUaRC4iiAJBtP%2BMCot0sFKM8A$
```

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. You should do `from time import time` instead of just `time`. Because the [`time` module has a `time` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) inside it.
2. [`math.ceil` returns a float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) and you are trying to use it as a dict after:

   ```
   expires = math.ceil(time() + 3000) ["expires"]
   ```

This doesn't make sense. `math.ceil(time() + 3000)` will be equal to something like `1400406364` and you can't retrieve a data from it.
Removing the `["expires"]` should solve the problem.

Comment: This is not the _actual_ problem.

Comment: the problem here im not able to pass expires to POST request  , and about timing its unix timing ,

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` *module* is not callable, you need to call `time` method from it:

```
>>> import time
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(time())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> math.ceil(time.time())
1400657920.0
```

Then you need to get rid of `["expires"]` after it, since it will return a float number not a dictionary.

I don't know why you are using cURL here, with [`requests`](http://requests.pocoo.org) your code is a lot simpler:

```
import time
import math
import urllib

import requests

url = 'http://api.videoplatform.limelight.com/rest/organizations/{}/media'
filename = 'foo/bar/zoo.txt'

params = {}
params['access_key'] = 'dfdfdeef'
params['expires'] = math.ceil(time.time()+3000)

url = '{}?{}'.format(url.format(org_id), urllib.urlquote(params))

payload = {}
payload['title'] = os.path.basename(filename)
payload['description'] = 'description'

file_data = {'media_file': open(filename, 'rb')}

result = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=file_data)

result.raise_for_status() # This will raise an exception if
                          # there is a problem with the request
```

Comment: still getting the same error even after importing time and math modules

Comment: plus i cant change the whole def and move to request instated of cURL  now , thanks for ur advise and tips

Comment: The import won't fix it, you need to change the call `mail.ceil(time.time())` (notice `time.time()`, you have `time()`)